# Help with structure of a sentence

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

The sentence is:

> The purpose of research is to analyze breastfeeding problems that arise for nursing mothers and solutions to them.

In this structure does the word *them* refer to *breastfeeding problems* as intended, or to *nursing mothers*?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please state where you found the sentence and what your research shows.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't omitted a verb like "find", so it should read "...and _find_ solutions to them"? Either way, the logical referent of "them" can only be the noun phrase "breastfeeding problems that arise for nursing mothers". One would expect research to find solutions to problems, not normally nursing mothers!

Comment: @BillJ Yes. I do hope that the solution to nursing mothers is not deemed to be nursing fathers!

Answer (score 2):

Because the sentence says solutions **to** them, I would say that it's referring to the problems.

We have solutions **to** problems, but solutions **for** people.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence appears to be missing a verb in the second half that would make the reference to *them* more clear:

> The purpose of research is **to analyze** breastfeeding problems that
>   arise for nursing mothers and **[insert verb]** solutions to them.